# Array Based Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++

Im trying to build an array based, "Binary Search Tree" by following the algorithm at:

http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/olcweb/cgi/pluginpop.cgi?it=gif%3A:600%3A:388%3A%3A/sites/dl/free/0070131511/25327/tree%5Finsert.gif%3A%3ATREE-INSERT

Up until I need to realloacte, my tree resembles:

```
     R
    / 
   A
    \
     F
      \
       L
      /
     B
      \
       C
        \
         T
```

Recursively. However, im notice that I need to get back to the root, "R"....Trying to do that now..

```
void BST::insert(const data& aData)
{
item *y = NULL;   // Algorithm calls for NULL assignment..
item *x = new item();       

     // How do i Init LEFT and RIGHT?
     // With no nested copy ctor for struct item?
if ( items->empty ) 
{
    items = new item();
    items->empty = false;
    items->theData = aData; // Get the data.
    ++size;
} 
else if ( size == maxSize ) this->reallocate();
else  
{   
        if ( aData < items->theData )
        {
            x[x->LEFT].theData = aData;
            x->LEFT = x->LEFT + 1;
            this->insert(items->theData);
        }
        else if ( items->theData < aData )
        {
            x[x->RIGHT].theData = aData;
            x->RIGHT = x->RIGHT + 1;
            this->insert(items->theData);
        } 
                       else this->insert(items->theData);
}
```

Here is my struct for the items array in the private section of the BST class object file:
...

```
 private:
    int size;  // size of the ever growing/expanding tree :)
    int maxSize;
    struct item
    {
              bool empty;
         int  LEFT;
              int  RIGHT;
              data theData;     
         };

    item *items;    // The tree array
    item *oldRoot;
         int root_index;   // index for the root(s)
```

Hmm. Im also overloading the assignment operator...I dont know what to say. Its hard. I've looked at so many examples and lectures online; as well as algorithms....

The relloaction method as requested:

```
void BST::reallocate()
{
    item *new_array = new item[size*2];
    for ( int array_index = 0; array_index < size; array_index++ ) 
    {
        new_array[array_index].theData = items[array_index].theData;
        new_array[array_index].empty = false;
    }
    size *= 2;
    delete [] items;

    items = NULL;
    items = new_array;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your reallocation method as well ?
Why don't you use a std::vector ?

Comment: I posted the reallocation method as u requested.

Answer (score 3):

There is well established way to implement binary tree as array, which says that root is sitting at index 0, `LEFT` of element at index *i* will be found at 2i + 1 and `RIGHT` will be found at 2i + 2. You do not need to have LEFT and RIGHT as part of your structure. 
it has to be

```
struct item
{
    int index;
    data theData;
};
```

Do **NOT** store left index and right index in your structure. Also you don't need to keep track of root index. It is always 0. Check out [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) on binary trees. Search for "Methods for storing binary trees" string.
This implementation allows easy traversal down and up the tree if needed.

Comment: Is there a reason why `item` contains an index? If it is implemented using an array then we know exactly where it is... Or am I missing something?